# PHP: for VS. foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Kindly someone explain to me about this?

```
$key = array_keys($aHash);
$size = sizeOf($key);
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) $aHash[$key[$i]] .= "a";
```

is faster than

```
foreach($aHash as $key=>$val) $aHash[$key] .= "a";
```

According to The PHP Benchmark. However I have a a code in my script:

```
My CODE:

foreach($_SESSION['undo'] as $key2=>$value2)
{
     if{
     }
     else
     {
     }
     .
     .
     .
     .
}
```

How can I convert a code like that as shown above to my code?
Kindly explain why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a foreach loop the first part is your array and the second part after the `as` is the current value when iterating.
When using a `for` loop you are working with indexes and have to manually access them. Just do the same as in your example. I'm assuming you are working with an associative array as you are using array keys.

```
$myArray = $_SESSION['undo'];
$keys = array_keys($myArray);
$size = sizeOf($keys);
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i ++) { 
    /* do something with $myArray[$keys[$i]] */
    echo $myArray[$keys[$i]];
}
```

Comment: the only thing I need is foreach($_SESSION['undo'] as $key2=>$value2)
{
} to be converted like as shown above i don't need ahash

Comment: it is convertet 1:1. "aHash" is only the variable name in your example above.

Comment: updated my code. has a typo in it.

Comment: ohhh wait my mistake what if i have only this i need a equivalent to $_SESSION['undo']['key'];

Answer (score 2):

do not count in for condition

you can try this

```
$size = count($_SESSION['undo']);
for($i = 0; $i< $size; $i++){
   $value = $_SESSION['undo'][$i];
}
```

Comment: This won't work if he was working with an associative array, what I thought he was doing because of the array keys he mentioned.

Comment: yes like this code is only be converted foreach($_SESSION['undo'] as $key2=>$value2)
{
}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i< count($_SESSION['undo']); $i++){
   $value = $_SESSION['undo'][$i];
}
```

Comment: Missing a closing `)` in your `count()`

Comment: i replace $i for $key? and $value for?

Comment: Don't use `count` on for loops, it's better to assign to a variable before, see @Harish answer, that's the idea

Answer (score 0):

Seems **you made a mistake**, from the http://www.phpbench.com/,

[image]

```
$key = array_keys($aHash);
$size = sizeOf($key);
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) $aHash[$key[$i]] .= "a";
```

This way cost **92 us**, just foreach cost **16 us**, with 'as' cost **21 us**.

Guys, wake up....

Comment: yeah my mistake. sorry